# Qt: Waiting for a signal using QEventLoop, what if the signal is emitted too early?

Tags: c++, qt, slot, qt-signals

I am working on an small client-server application. The client sends a query and has to wait for an answer. I think the most convenient way is to use a QEventLoop:

```
connect(&parser, SIGNAL(answer_received()), this, SLOT(react_to_answer()));
...
...
QEventLoop loop;
connect(&parser, SIGNAL(answer_received()), &loop, SLOT(quit()));
this.sendQuery();
loop.exec();
```

This worked for me at the moment, but what happens, if the signal `answer_received()` is emitted very fast, even before `loop.exec()` was called? Will my application stuck in the QEventLoop forever?

Thank you!

Comment: In about all event-driven GUI systems (including JavaScript in a browser, and the Windows API) the events do not happen asynchronously, but only when explicitly waited for by the code. While the code does someting else events may be queued up. I would be very much surprised if Qt is different in this respect.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Qt signals are not events and "generally" end up in synchronous direct calls.

Comment: @Velkan Calling `QEventLoop::exec()` sets `QEventLoopPrivate::exit` to `false`, so calling `QEventLoop::quit()` does not prevent the event loop from running.

Comment: @BenjaminT: False dichotomy.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Not that false, or your first comment would be true. Nothing in Qt prevents the `quit()` slot to be called during the `sendQuery()` call, especially because connections are much more like simple function calls than events. To ensure that `quit()` is called after `loop.exec()`, one would have to force going through Qt event system in some way, like explicitly specifying that the connection is queued.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given your code, the only way you will encounter an issue is if the `answer_received()` signal is emitted before `loop.exec()` is called. Which is equivalent to say that `answer_received()` is emitted during the call to `this.sendQuery();`.

In your case it is not likely to happen because you rely on server/client interactions and you likely use a `QNetworkAccessManager` or a `QSocket` of some sort. If this is the case the QNetworkAccessManager/QSocket will not emit `readyRead()` or `finished()` signals until you enter the event loop.

However, in a more general case if `answer_received()` can be emitted from `this.sendQuery()` you have to change your code:

1. You could make the connection between to be queued. This way even if `answer_received()` is emitted during `this.sendQuery()` the slot will not be called until you enter the event loop.

   ```
   connect(&parser, SIGNAL(answer_received()), &loop, SLOT(quit()), Qt::QueuedConnection);
   ```
2. You could ensure that `answer_received()` is never emitted during `this.sendQuery()`. On way to do so is to use 0ms QTimer, which will trigger as soon as all events in the event queue are processed, i.e during `loop.exec()`

   Replace:

   ```
   emit answer_received();
   ```

   By:

   ```
   QTimer::singleShot(0, this, *receiver, &MyClass::answer_received);
   ```

Comment: Thank you very much, your answer makes sense. I had the concern you mentioned in the first sentence.